# What is the license of the content of the WILDLABS forum?

Tags: community, dissemination

[WILDLABS](https://wildlabs.net/) introduces itself as being the

> the first global, **open online community** dedicated to conservation technology.

They have a large [discussion website](https://wildlabs.net/discussions) which could be quite complementary to this Bioacoustics SE site as suggested several times on meta or the main SE site (e.g., [as a forum](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/182/73), [as a directory or  teaching/job resource](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wildlab)).

I'm wondering about the "openness" of their [discussion platform](https://wildlabs.net/discussions). Does anyone know whether the content of the forum is under an open-sharing license? I have not found this information on their website.

PS: see this [SE question](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/q/1132/73) for the status of the WILDLABS community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is outlined in the [Terms of Use](https://www.wildlabs.net/terms-use) and [Community Guidelines](https://wildlabs.net/page/community-guidelines) documents.

Of note,

> "Any content you upload to our site will be considered
> non-confidential and non-proprietary. You retain all of your ownership
> rights in your content, but you are required to grant us and FFI and
> other users of the website an unlimited worldwide non-exclusive
> licence to use, store and copy that content and to distribute and make
> it available to third parties."

And

> "As explained in our Website Terms of Use, content that you upload must not infringe the rights of any other person or organisation."

I talk more about WILDLABS' features in my answer to your other question [here](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/a/1136/200). I agree there is a lot of complementarity between the 2 sites!